# Mark audiences in document with multiaudience

Tags: color

I am using the package multiaudience to separate different levels of detail in a document. While within the LaTeX-Code I can clearly separate the content for the different audiences, there is no option to see the differences in the compiled file.

For example, the following creates a document with one line only shown to audience A, a different line shown to everyone.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multiaudience} 
\begin{document}
    \SetNewAudience{A}
    \DefCurrentAudience{A}
    \begin{shownto}{A}
        Show this only to audience A.
    \end{shownto}

    Show this to every audience.
\end{document}
```

In the final document, the content specific to audience A and content for all groups looks the same. I would like to create an "editor's view" of the final document, for example by distinguishing the audiences by text colours or a bar on the side with the name of the audience that this line is shown to.

[image: Image containing the text "Show this only to audience A. Show this to every audience."]

I know that you can change the colour of your text by using the `\color` of the `xcolor` package, but I don't know how to get this into the audience commands.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.